# Limits trigonometry

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Evaluate $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0} \sin (a\pi\cos(b\arcsin(x))-1)\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}}$

I was thinking about applying L'Hospital rule but I do not think this is the right way to solve it.

Can you give me a hint? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is this Question from ? What are $a$ & $b$ ? There may be no limit , limit may be finite or limit may be infinite. Details may be missing here. We can not use LH rule when Numerator is not $0$ with $0$ Denominator. I think , $-1$ changing to $-a\pi$ can let us use LH rule.

Comment: a & b are real numbers

Comment: When $a$ & $b$ are the most general real numbers , we will have too many Cases to check. Where is this Question from ?

Comment: You could try Taylor series. There are definitely multiple cases to deal with, but I think they're manageable.